# How to add infinite scroll in react redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add infinite scroll in my react app which uses redux for state management. I tried doing this But it doesn't work at all. My data comes from api `www.xxxxx.com/message?page=1&items=20` when I need to fetch data from second page my api should be `www.xxxxx.com/message?page=2&items=20` which shoul get dispatch when user reaches to bottom of scroll element. I have no idea how to run this function.

these are my codes

> actions

```
export const loadMoreMessage = (userId, vendorId, productId, page, size) => dispatch =>{
    dispatch({
        type: LOAD_MORE_MESSAGE_LOAD,
    });
    new _rest().get(`message?userId=${userId}&vendorid=${vendorId}&productid=${productId}&page=${page}&size=${size}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOAD_MORE_MESSAGE_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOAD_MORE_MESSAGE_ERROR,
                error:err
            })
    })
}
```

I was also trying to use `reduxlazy load` npm package but when i try to run this it goes to infinite loop.

This how i added this.

```
<Grid  item xs={12}>
                    <div ref = {this.ref} style={{maxHeight: '500px', height: '500px',
                        position: 'fixed',width:'100%',
                        overflow: 'auto', paddingBottom: '50px'}} ref={(ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref}>
                        <div>
                        <ReduxLazyScroll
                            isFetching={message.isLoading}
                            errorMessage={message.fetchError}
                            loadMore={() => this.handleLoadMessage()}
                    >
                    {receivedMessage &&
                    receivedMessage.map((item,index) => {
                        console.log('chatM', item)
                        if(item.senderId === item.vendorId) {
                            return (
                                <ChatThread key={index}  image={item.reciverImage} content={item.content}/>
                            )

                        }else {
                            return (
                                <ChatThread key={index} image={item.senderImage} right={true} content={item.content}/>
                            )
                        }
                    }) }
                    </ReduxLazyScroll>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </Grid>
```

>

```
handleLoadMessage = () => {

        this.props.loadMoreMessage(
            this.props.match.params.userId,
            this.props.match.params.vendorId,
            this.props.match.params.productId,
            this.props.pageInfo.currentPage + 1,
            20
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not passing params to your action

```
export const loadMoreMessage = (userId, vendorId, productId, page, size) => dispatch =>{
```

```
...
<ReduxLazyScroll
  isFetching={message.isLoading}
  errorMessage={message.fetchError}
  // Here you have to pass action params
  loadMore={() => this.handleLoadMessage(userId, vendorId, productId, page, size)}
>
...
```